# Svn ignore with coda subversion

Tags: svn, coda

i am using coda on my mac as an editor and using the built in svn client which is very helpful indeed.

However it lacks the ignore functionality for a file and i am trying to do it via command line

Via terminal i went to the folder from which i want to exclude a file
and run this command
"svn propedit svn:ignore database.php ."

I got this as a result

svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found

Can i get some help on that please?

Answer (score 2):

The `svn propedit` or `svn pedit` command requires an editor in order to work, and that's what your error message is telling you. You need to set up an *environment variable* that contains the name of the editor you want to use.

The Mac has several text editors that can work. Remember, you're not talking about things like `TextEdit`, but terminal editors. For example, you can look at `vim`, `pico`, and `emacs`. I prefer `vim`, but that can be fairly difficult for a person who has never been exposed to it to understand. You can try `pico` which is friendlier.

To set an environment variable in your shell, you'd do something like this:

```
$ EDITOR=pico; export EDITOR
```

What Subversion does is take the editors in the following order:

- Whatever `SVN_EDITOR` is set to. If this isn't set...
- Whatever `VISUAL` is set to. If this isn't set...
- Whatever `EDITOR` is set to. If this isn't set, you're in trouble

Most of the time, you set your editor environment variable in your `$HOME/.profile` file or if you're using bash, your `$HOME/.bash_profile` file. This way, when you first log in, your editor will be set.

Another method is to edit the `$HOME/.subversion/config` file to set your editor there. This will override your environment variable settings.

Take a look at that file, and you'll see a section like this:

```
### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor-cmd to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
###   et al).
# editor-cmd = editor (vi, emacs, notepad, etc.)
```

You'll be changing that last line by removing the `#` in front, and setting `editor-cmd` to your favorite editor:

```
### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor-cmd to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
###   et al).
editor-cmd = pico
```

If none of this makes sense to you, it's about time to learn a bit about the underlying Unix system that's at the heart of your Mac. You might want to look at [Take Control of the Mac Command Line with Terminal](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781933671550.do) as a first step.  After that, I recommend to look at some of O'Reilly's BASH command shell books since that's what the Mac's shell defaults to.

I would also recommend you learn [VI/VIM](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529833.do). This is an old editor first published by Bill Joy in 1976. Bill Joy would later be famous for founding Sun Microsystems and his work on NFS, Sparc, and Java. He also wrote the [C Shell](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/#b), but I'm willing to let that ride.

Anyway, this 37 year old editor is probably the most powerful programming editor ever invented (and don't listen to those EMAC people. [They're just a cult group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)). It can be tough for a beginner, but once you've learned it, you'll find it fast, simple, and powerful.